# NextJS wrong CSS order on production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I import CSS files from local files and node modules:

```
//> Global Styling
// Local
import "../styles/globals.scss";
// Icons
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
// Bootstrap
import "bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css";
// Material Design for Bootstrap
import "mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css";
```

This works as intended on my local development version. All styles appear as they should be.

As you can see here, the styling is different on local and production.
(Take a look at font and buttons)

[image: Development left, Production right]
*(Development left, Production right)*

My `next.config.js` is:

```
//#region > Imports
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
//#endregion

//#region > Exports
module.exports = [
  withSass({
    webpack(config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
          },
        },
      });

      return config;
    },
  }),
  withPlugins([withCSS, withFonts, withImages]),
];
//#endregion

/**
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: (EUPL-1.2)
 * Copyright © 2020 InspireMedia GmbH
 */
```

It seems the MDB styling is being overwritten by bootstrap on building the app. I deploy my app by using `next build && next export && firebase deploy` and use the `./out` folder for deployment source.

You can find the code here: [https://github.com/aichner/nextjs-redux-template](https://github.com/aichner/nextjs-redux-template/tree/add-basics-aa1)

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one to have this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16630). In short, code splitting is breaking import order in production. I'd recommend posting your repo in the issue.

Comment: any solution for this ?? i m also facing same issue

Answer (score 3):

*If the issue is incorrect styling. (as you are using material-ui) :*

1. Create *_document.js* under pages directory.
2. Fill the file with following code :

```
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/styles"; // works with @material-ui/core/styles, if you prefer to use it.
import theme from "../Theme"; // change this theme path as per your project

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* Not exactly required, but this is the PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

***Reason :*** Material UI uses context behind the scenes to apply its styling. Due to NextJs server side rendering, this context will be lost. So, we need to tell Next to make use of that previous context. The above code does that.