# Ordering problem using css import alongside styled components in nextjs app

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I am using NextJS and when I use direct css `import ...css` alongside a styled-component `createGlobalStyle`. My direct css imports are always included last in my html causing some overriding issues that I've setup in GlobalStyles.

How can I resolve this?

**rendered html**

```
<head>
    <link href="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1609163560022">
    <style></style> // global styled component
    <style></style> // bootstrap imported after global styled component
</head>
```

**_app.js**

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' // this is always loaded last <head>
import GlobalStylesfrom 'styles/global'; // this is always loaded first in <head>

const theme = {
  ...
};

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles/>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

**_document.js**

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const page = renderPage(App => props =>
      sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
    );
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();
    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>{this.props.styleTags}</Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've had similar issues and ended up having a file for external css imports, local gloal css and switched positions until I ended up with what I was looking for. Very annoying indeed. Seems like you're not the only one to have this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16630). 
There you can find my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088186/nextjs-wrong-css-order-on-production-build)

Comment: hey thanks very much for this! it's a bummer, I tried to copy paste the entire bootstrap.min into a styled component so I can respect the order but something in that bootstrap css is breaking styled component and nothing gets imported. I'll have to debug this more.

Comment: That's exactly what I've tried before too. I actually have the bootstrap.min.js still as a local minified stylesheet.